# Find column from multiple column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have one question about database query. Please refer below table.

```
Table : 1
ID   Country
1    x
2    y
3    z
4    k


Table : 2
eng  fre  fre1   fre2
x    x
x1   k      y   t
x2          n     z

Output Table
id  country
1   x
2   x1
3   x2
4   x1
```

How to achieve this in Hive?

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join three times but it may run slow:

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.eng, c.eng, d.eng)  as Country
  from table_1 a
       left join table_2 b on a.country=b.fre
       left join table_2 c on a.country=c.fre1
       left join table_2 d on a.country=d.fre2
;
```

Comment: First option will not work in my case because Hive is not supporting pivot. Only option remaining is second option which I already used but as you mentioned I have 2.2 million records that's why query takes forever to execute.

Comment: 1st query should work on Hive since there is nothing that Hive is not support in it. Subqueries are supported, coalesce() and max() are also supported. Please try to run it, it should work good

Comment: This `--pivot table2 ` is just a comment.

Comment: I am getting output table as id is fine but country as null. I guess when you are doing max(coalesce at that time it is taking only fre name from table 2 where as table 1 contains either name as fre or fre1 or fre2. But we want only eng correspond to that fre or fre1 or fre2 in output table.

Comment: Most probably your table2 contains not NULL values . Maybe empty strings?

Comment: Please try to replace table_2 with this subquery `(select eng, 
                              case when fre='' then null else fre end fre,
                              case when fre1='' then null else fre1 end fre1,
                              case when fre2='' then null else fre2 end fre2
                           from table_2
                           ) table_2`

Comment: coalesce can pick wrong value if instead of nulls there are some values. I'm not sure empty strings or space characters. You better know your data

Comment: I got your point. Please see Table 2 in my updated question. I hope that will be more clear now.  I guess now you will understand my point. Please can you tell me hive query based on my updated table 2. Really thank you so much for your help here.

Comment: Now the option 2 is the only possible. Removed option1 from my  answer.

Comment: I see. I applied option 2 but in my case as I mentioned you that my table 1 has more than 2.2 million records which gonna slow down query. But yes really thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: BTW TEZ instead of MR should run these joins in parallel. Something like this: 1 - mapper vertex(reading tbl1), 2-  mapper(reading 2), 3, 4, 5 reducers should run in parallel. I cannot check right now.

Comment: Yes I already set my hive execution engine as tez. Thanks for information.